# Google Profile API user model (

Tags: google-profiles-api

I'm trying to create an AS3 based provisioning client, without php. 
Now i'm creating the user management part, whereby i receive all user information, from our domain, which is a success, but i stuck now at building the client side model for google user, for which i need all of the properties, which can be provided by google. 
For that, could somebody please provide me a link, whereby i can check the data model of a user received from https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/{domain}/full/{user} address? Similar to this: https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people
I beleive i tried everything to find, maybe the answer is obvious, but i just couldn't find any solution (except go trough on the atom feed, one by one, and create the object based on that properties, but this is also not sufficient, since if an information is not filled up, it won't be exist in the feed)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The data model for a Google Apps user profile from the feed https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/{domain}/full/{user} is documented starting at the [Profiles API page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/profiles/) and then you will need to access the core Contacts reference info for the [Contact kind](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements#gdContactKind) and the [Profile kind](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements#gdProfileKind).